# Issue with color fillling in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a calendar table with data based on some conditions. The color gets filled only in the boxes where there is data and the empty boxes are not colored. How do I get all the boxes colored irrespective of the data's presence?

```
    =IIf(DateDiff("d",Fields!EndofDate.Value, Fields!EndDate.Value) > 0 ,"White","Yellow")
```

Please help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the textbox properties of your date field, click on Fill, then click on the expression button next to Fill Color and enter the following expression:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!EndofDate.Value),"White","Yellow")
```

That will make all the fields with NULL values have a white background and all others have a yellow background.

Answer (score 0):

I have possibly another solution which you can try, instead of using a `IsNothing` you can use a `Choose` function

E.g. `=Choose(Fields!change.Value+1, "Gold", "Blue"....)`

So if there is no change instead of `"Gold"` you can just insert `""`